# Adding AutoComplete attribute to textbox in Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In Razor I can turn off Autocomplete on a textbox by doing this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

Is there a way I can specify this in the ViewModel using DataAnnotations instead of in the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way to manipulate html attributes from ViewModel attributes with the `EditorFor` extension method.

However, you can create a **custom html helper method** if you want to keep it DRY.

Btw I don't think that it would be a great idea to encapsulate these kind of informations (html attributes) inside a ViewModel class.

Comment: Isn't that the point of the DataAnnotations though? Or am I missing the point? I assumed you wanted to keep the View as light as possible and have the ViewModel handle information like this.

Comment: Yes, the view should be as light as possible but that doesn't mean you should move view specific information somewhere else. For example validation attributes on viewmodel properties are a good usage of dataannotations but what you want is a very view specific thing.

Comment: If there are some logic in the application which determines if autocomplete is needed or not then of course that isn't the view's responsibility but here you just want to set an html attribute. Html is the view of an asp.net mvc application, this is the reason why I would keep this in the view.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was attempting to try to keep these things all in one place. I'll keep it in the view based on your recommendation. Thanks!